# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly This may be due to a blocked port

Tags: php, mysql

```
2:56:41 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.<br>
2:56:41 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, <br>
2:56:41 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.<br>
2:56:41 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check<br>
2:56:41 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues<br>
2:56:41 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this<br>
2:56:41 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums<br>
```

[image]

MySQL does not start I have already tried port 8080 like

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 8080

#Listen 12.34.56.78:8081
Listen 8081

another

<VirtualHost _default_:4443>

# General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost:4443
```

anything does not work for me

Comment: What is this, WAMP, XAMPP, some other \*AMP? Have you tried pressing the Logs button or check Windows Event Viewer? And that config file is for Apache and won't do anything for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious think: give a look at the mysql logs.

Also, try to start mysql from a console using `mysqld --verbose` to see if there are any error, this should give you a hint on the solution

A last thing: the configuration snipped you posted seems to refer to a web server, so it is useless to understand why mysql does not start.